# filter to get rid of blank array entries gives no error, but does not work (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I hope I just missing something simple, but I for the life of me cant see why this doesn't work:

```
// GET ALL SHEET NAMES FROM THE SPREADSHEET AND PUT INTO AN ARRAY
function sheetNames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {

        out.push( [ checkSheetName(sheets[i].getName()) ] )

  }
  Logger.log("before : " + out);
  var listOfsheets = out.filter(function(x){  return (x !== (undefined || null || '')); });

  Logger.log("after : " + listOfsheets);
  return listOfsheets ;

}

// SEARCH ALL SHEETS AND ONLY SELECT THEM IF THEY HAVE THE TEXT "REPORT_" IN THE NAME
function checkSheetName(sheetName) {
  var checkFor = 'Report_'
  if (sheetName.indexOf(checkFor) >= 0) {
        return sheetName;
    } else {
      sheetName = '';
      return sheetName;
    }
```

My logger shows the exact same result before and after its been put through the filter. An error would be great, but runs fine... just doesn't seem to do anything.

I suppose another question would be, can I put something in the initial  getSheets() so that it only gets what I need in the first place? But Even if that is possible, I'm still curious about why my filter doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`x` is an **array** *rather than* an **array-item string**, make it

```
out.push( checkSheetName(sheets[i].getName()) ); //observe that array wrapping is removed
```

You can shorten your code by doing (*assuming that sheets is array-like, not a direct array*)

```
return Array.from( sheets ).filter( x => !!checkSheetName( x.getName() ) );
```

If `sheets` is an array then make it

```
return sheets.filter( x => !!checkSheetName( x.getName() ) );
```

or even without `checkSheetName`

```
return sheets.filter( x => !!( x.getName().indexOf( "Report_" ) != -1 ) );
```

Comment: This is an elegant alternative, but it's worth mentioning that a `for` loop is way, way faster than `filter`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Agree, but difference is noticable only **when the number of items to iterate are quite high** (don't  have any number to say **how much high**).

Comment: Thank you! I went with the first one - The others seem more efficient, but I got syntax errors, and its too late at night to figure why :P

@GerardoFurtado, as for volume its only 3 sheets at this stage, so speed isn't an issue- but I will keep that in mind if it grows

Answer (score 0):

```
out.filter(function(x){  return (x !== (undefined || null || '')); });
```

Your filter function reduces to

```
out.filter(function (x) {  return (x !== ''); });
```

because the engine looks inside the parentheses and parses from left to right:

```
(x !== (undefined || null || ''))
// undefined is falsy, replace with expression on the right
(x !== (null || ''))
// null is falsy, replace with expression on the right
(x !== '')
```

Now look at what you're filtering:

```
out.push( [ checkSheetName(sheets[i].getName()) ] )
```

Here, you push a new array with one element onto the `out` array. Drop the square brackets to just push the name.

Since `x` is always an array, it is never the empty string, and your filter filters out nothing. Even if you drop the brackets making `x` an array, if `x` is `null` or `undefined`, it will still pass your filter. Replace your filter with

```
out.filter(Boolean);
```

This will coerce your array value to a boolean. The empty string, `null`, and `undefined` are all falsy and return `false`. Other strings are truthy and return `true`, the exact filtering you need.